# Flutter Circular Avatar does not support Image from storage

Tags: flutter

I am looking for one widget which can handle both images(network image and storage image) in a circular shape. I have to select one image from storage if not available on network. I used many widgets and find CircleAvatar best among them. It makes circular shape if you put image in backgroundImage. It needs ImageProvider parameter. How I can to use Image.file(_file) in backgroundImage to pass it as a ImageProvider.

```
CircleAvatar(
            radius: 80.0,
            backgroundImage:
             //   NetworkImage("${imageNotfound}"), // NetowrkImage extends ImageProvider class, so it works
             Image.file(_file),                   // How to convert my Image class to ImageProvider???
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          )
```

Note: My main concern is,use any single widget which have circular shape property for both(network image and storage image).

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it as follows 
**local asset**

```
    CircleAvatar(
  radius: 50.0,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/image.jpg"),
)
```

**network**

```
    CircleAvatar(
  radius: 50.0,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083475219-aed59281b9aa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
)
```